# Unloading a window in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm looking for a Firefox-specific way to unload the current window when the URL changes. If I don't unload the window, content doesn't load correctly when the user presses the 'Back' button. Internet Explorer displays the behavior I want - it loads things okay. So I don't want to add any code that breaks that.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
if (typeof clientInformation == 'undefined') {
    window.addEventListener('unload', UnloadHandler, false);
};  

function UnloadHandler() {
    //do nothing
};
```

Is this the best way to do this or are there easier ways?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `onbeforeunload` listener in Firefox:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

Comment: The problem with this is that IE < 9 doesn't accept the addEventListener and breaks the script. that's what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Jes I know my bad but I think I asked my question wrong. firefox has a cache behavior that uses in-memory caching for entire web pages, including their JavaScript states. so when I clicked a link and go back (back button) the page has to lets say 'refresh'.

Comment: I think you might need to regroup your thoughts and create a new question with more precise details of what you want to do.

Comment: My problem is that in my current situation the when I push the back button in ie the page looks fine but when in FF the content is hidden because I animate it when clicking a link. When I refresh the page in FF the page slides the content down like it's is suppost to do.

Comment: I now just use jquery $(window).bind("unload", function() {
  });